# git Push local branch to remote, RPC failed

Tags: git, centos, push, branch, git-remote

I know the command for do what I want (to push a local branch to the remote repository) but there's an error:

```
[root@XXX app-name]# git push -u origin SomeBranch
Password:
Counting objects: 21, done.
Compressing objects: 100% (11/11), done.
Writing objects: 100% (11/11), 260.55 KiB, done.
Total 11 (delta 10), reused 0 (delta 0)
error: RPC failed; result=22, HTTP code = 417
```

And then it get stucked. What is happening? I'm connecting through putty (from Windows) to my local virtual machine (Centos 64), the remote repository is in another server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix it. I had to use SSH instead http/https.